# Compiling a C file from a java Class

Tags: java, c, windows, compilation

```
import java.io.*;

public class chk 
{
    String className;
    String command,command1,command2;
    public String getMsg(String fileName,File Path1) 
    {
        String dir;
        command = "tcc "+fileName;
        String output = executeCommand(command,Path1);
        if(output.compareTo("")==0)             
            output = "Compilation Successfull!!";
        return output;
    }

    private String executeCommand(String command,File Path1) 
    {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        Process p;
        try 
        {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command,null,Path1);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";           
            while ((line = reader1.readLine())!= null) 
            {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }
            while ((line = reader2.readLine())!= null) 
            {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return output.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        String x;
        File dir=new File("D:\\test");
        chk ob = new chk();
        x = ob.getMsg("hello.c",dir);
        System.out.println("OUtput : "+x);
    }
}
```

ERROR

[image]

I am trying to compile a C code from a java class. I am using Turbo C/C++ compiler and have also set its path i.e "C:/TC/bin" even my programs are compiling when i compile them directly from command prompt but when i am trying to compile it with a java file the following error message appears. HELP!!

Comment: @TonythePony which compiler should i use to run on windows ?

Comment: MinGW is popular (and free): http://www.mingw.org/

Comment: You're less likely to run into any environment issues, since you don't need the MS-DOS subsystem, but there might be other problems.

Comment: Oh dear, *why* are you still using a 16-bit compiler in 2014!?

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems fine after adding a missing import: `import java.io.*;` however it seems you're using a very old compiler that's made for 16-bit /DOSWindows and that is probably the reason it won't work for you.

Try using a modern compiler like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) instead, for Windows you'll want to use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) which is a version of the GCC compiler built for Windows. I tried your code using GCC 4.8.2 (MinGW) and it worked fine.

Another alternative would be to use Microsofts Visual C++ compiler which also can be run from the command line, (but be aware that it only supports C89, with some features from later standards).

Comment: @rick Through the MinGW project, yes.

Comment: @rick To use GCC with your program you'll need to change the `command = "tcc "+fileName;` to `command = "gcc "+fileName;`